# Why use ASSET_PATH over Image-url when linking images in css in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, precompile

Let me start off by saying this is the worst part about rails. Coming from a .NET background, it's so easy to just write css like you would any standard HTML page but, nope, not in Rails, it blows up unless you do all this special crap.

My question is essentially this: why could I only get my images to load through the asset pipeline when i added a .erb to the end of application.css and wrote the background-image property like this:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>);
```

I don't get why these wouldn't work (ive tried 100 different things):

```
background-image: url('/assets/image.png');
background-image: url('assets/image.png');
background-image: image-url('image.png');
background-image: image-url('assets/image.png');
background-image: url(image.png);
```

FYI this is my production environment and everything is precompiled. Everything was working in development by just linking this way:

```
 background-image url('/assets/image.png');
```

but when I switched to production and precompiled, any image or font file had to be converted to the ASSET_PATH method of doing things or the images wouldnt show up....common issue?

Comment: I believe fingerprinting has something to do with it. Have you looked at the resulting generated CSS file and what the urls have turned in to? The Rails asset pipeline does a good amount, check in to it for a better explanation -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Did you ever end up finding the answer to this question? I'm having the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998738/

Comment: No man, I just threw the images that are used in my css in the "Public/images" folder, and then you can just do CSS the normal way, as in "url(images/image.png)", since the images aren't sent through the pipeline that way.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something like this in your `config/environments/production.rb` file:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

That's why it won't serve them directly.

As an aside: I've done .NET and Rails a good bit. A lot of this is just the differences between Rails and other systems. I do understand your frustration, though.

Comment: My frustration continues because config.serve_static_assets is set to true I believe. I have literally done hours of research on this before I asked here, so all of the obviously solutions have not worked. It has to be something with my apache or vhost conf file perhaps...ill do more research on that. It's all really frustrating, but hopefully once I figure it out, I'll never have to deal with this again, lol