# Rails 4.1 image url's still calling uncompiled assets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, precompile

So I have got my rails site up on production for the most part but I realized I was missing a few images. I looked at my precompiled css file and the image url's are calling the images directly like `url(/assets/gototop.png)` which it won't find since my image is now something like `gototop-6c119f88349ddd550e3efcf5bbefe1ad.png`.

How do I get my css to point to the precompiled image file?

Update: also as stated in the linked file I realize I could use the asset_path method but unfortunately I am using scss and I can't just add .erb to the end of the file...seems rails doesnt like to work with multiple compilers. (I tried)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem caused by [asset fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) (not just a Rails 4.1 issue)

---

The way to fix it is to use a precompiler in your CSS (Rails comes with [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)). A precompiler basically means you can treat CSS files like `erb` -- use certain helpers & variables:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass
body
  background: asset_url("/layout/gototop.png")
```

---

`asset_url` (seems it's now called [`asset-url`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)) basically allows you to call assets by their fingerprinted name

As per our discussion, you also need to do this with `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`. After firing this command in the console, it worked as expected

Comment: sorry i marked this as the answer too quickly. This still isn't working. I get a url that still doesn't point to the compiled png inside of the compiled css

Comment: `background: asset-url("gototop.png") no-repeat;` <--- in the css.scss file turns into `background: url(/assets/gototop.png) no-repeat;` in the compiled file

Comment: Are you precompiling Bill?

Comment: Yes I did a `rake assets:precompile` `rake assets:clean` and then even touched my tmp/restart.txt file

Comment: I even made a more significant change so that the precompile would pick it up...still no go

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute this code via ERB first:

**Step 1 RENAME**: `RAILS_ROOT/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass` to `RAILS_ROOT/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass.erb`

**Step 2 ADD ERB TAGS**:
change asset path to use erb tags

```
body
  background: <%= asset_url("/layout/gototop.png") %>
```

to verify it worked, see the filename of `gototop.png`, it should be something like `gototop-029908d2eb2fd4cb3a2f538c6acbd73d.css`.

if not, then post back with sample app on github, so we can help you debug this.

Comment: I actually did this first. The precompiler did not like having multiple compilers (.sass.erb) and failed